# Why should we use OutputStream.write(byte[] b, int off, int len) instead of OutputStream.write(byte[] b)?

Tags: java-io, fileoutputstream

Sorry, everybody. It's a Java beginner question, but I think it will be helpful for a lot of java learners.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();    
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len;
while((len=fis.read(buffer)) != -1){
    os.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
```

The code above is part of FileSenderClient class which is for sending files from client to a server using java.io and java.net.Socket.

My question is that: in the above code, why should we use

```
os.write(buffer, 0, len)
```

instead of

```
os.write(buffer)
```

In another way to ask this question: what is the point of having a "len" parameter for "OutputStream.write()" method?

It seems both codes are working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while((len=fis.read(buffer)) != -1){
    os.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
```

Because you only want to write data that you actually read. Consider the case where the input consists of *N* buffers plus one byte. Without the `len` parameter you would write `(N+1)*1024` bytes instead of `N*1024+1` bytes. Consider also the case of reading from a socket, or indeed the general case of reading: the actual contract of `InputStream.read()` is that it transfers at least one byte, *not* that it fills the buffer. Often it can't, for one reason or another.

> It seems both codes are working fine.

No they're not.

Answer (score -1):

It actually does not work in the same way.

It is very likely you used a very small text file to test. But if you look carefully, you will still find there is a lot of extra spaces in the end of you file you received, and the size of the file you received is larger than the file you send.

The reason is that you have created a byte array in a size of 1024 but you don't have so many data to put (or read()) into that byte array. Therefore, the byte array is full with NULL in the end part. When it comes to writing to file, these NULLs are still written into the file and show as spaces " " in Windows Notepad...

If you use advanced text editors like Notepad++ or Sublime Text to view the file you received, you will see these NULL characters.

Comment: They will only be null on the first read, if it is short. After that they can be anything, i.e. junk left over from the previous read.