# Download large video file getting corrupted

Tags: java, tomcat

In server side code, I have set buffer size and content length as *File.length()* and then Opened File using *FileInputStream*. 
Later fetching output stream using *HttpResponse.getOutputStream()* and dumping bytes of data that is read using *FileInputStream*

I am using Apache Tomcat 7.0.52, Java 7

---

On Client
File Downloader.java

```
URL url = new URL("myFileURL");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setConnectTimeout(10000);
con.setReadTimeout(10000);
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setUseCaches(false);
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
con.connect();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("filename");
if(con.getResponseCode()==200){
    InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
    int readVal;
    while((readVal=is.read())!=-1) fos.write(readVal);
}
fos.flush()
fos.close();
```

So above code failed to download large file.
On client using Java 7

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. "download failing" isn't a precise problem description.

Comment: You just edited your code **after** @lance-java answer. I don't think this is a good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can You try this

```
 FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
 int bytesRead;
 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
 while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
     outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
 }
```

---

Quoting from https://stackoverflow.com/a/45453874/4121845

> Because you only want to write data that you actually read. Consider the case where the input consists of N buffers plus one byte. Without the len parameter you would write (N+1)*1024 bytes instead of N*1024+1 bytes. Consider also the case of reading from a socket, or indeed the general case of reading: the actual contract of InputStream.read() is that it transfers at least one byte, not that it fills the buffer. Often it can't, for one reason or another.

Comment: Above code worked, But i dont get how that created corrupted data. If what i understand from quoted thing is correcnt it means to say there will be junk data last buffer. How did that corrupt my file. it never happens so when file copy locally. Can you share me some more information @acxz94

Answer (score 1):

```
    fos.flush();
} finally {
    fos.close();
    con.close();
}
```

Comment: While correct and probably approriate regarding the effort put in the question, maybe elaborating a bit more than just code-dumping would be helpful :)

Comment: Ok @Ben can u suggest a subject for this please?