# Download Manager program failed on lower bandwidth

Tags: java, tomcat7

I am trying to create a download manage using java. So i was successful in downloading files when i have good bandwidth. But when i switched to my mobile hosted network, file failed to download. So i am assuming the cause was due to lower bandwidth.

Anyone help me out with this issue. I am using Apache Tomcat 7 and my download manager is created using java.

You can find my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50700146/download-large-video-file-getting-corrupted/50701550#50701550).

```
 FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
   int bytesRead;
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
   while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
       outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
 }
```

Comment: Could it be that you have used the code from the first answer to your previous question but not the second?

Comment: Nope its after resolving only.. Ty @StefanLindner for changes :)